# Logical systems and formal proof

Tags: reference-request, formal-proofs, formal-systems

Is there any good book dealing with various formal systems and a book for formal proofs. Or atleast some good notes.

This page on wikipedia also says: 'This article needs attention from an expert in mathematics'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_systems

Comment: If by formal proof you are not only referring to logic proofs only, but formal proof in general, Daniel Velleman's How To Prove It is a pretty good choice. The book has ample amount of exercises, and this guy has worked out all the solutions. 
http://technotes-himanshu.blogspot.hk/2010/05/how-to-prove-it-ch4-sec41ordered-pairs.html

Peter Smith also wrote a pretty good guide on reference for readings of logic, depending on your level:
http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/